# Hyperlinking to a nonserver machine

Tags: dbase

My church has a management software that we would like to have several people access at the same time but over the internet. We have a website but it is hosted by another company. Is it possible to create a hyperlink on our website to access this program on our office computer? The hyperlink would be setup so that it is not visible to those who don't have access to the program. We have tried several remote access program such as TeamView and Go2MyPC. These give access to the entire computer and that is not something we want either. If we can't do the hyperlink is it possible for us to turn this computer into a server and access it that way> Again the focus is for at least 5 people to be able to use this software at the same time should that need arise.

Our church management software is designed to be run on a network. We have already setup the user IDs and passwords for the group who currently have access to the it. The problem is that we only have one office computer and all of or group  can't use it at one time because the each have access to different parts. I.e. Treasurer can only acces financial module, clerk can only access membership roster and so on. The goal is to find the path of least resistance that will allow as many of these people to access this software at the same time as possible remotely. I understand the security issues so to that I ask if anyone thinks we should get another computer to make into a server or turn this on we have into one.

Is there an advantage to hosting our own website on our machine where the management software is already located?

Answer (score 1):

You actually have three different problems:

- You are trying to use a "nonserver machine" as a server.  I assume it doesn't have a static IP address; a static hyperlink will fail.  Since you have a web site, you can set up your Management Software Server (for lack of a better name) to check in with your web site server, which will hold the latest IP address for your MSS.  Your users can then check in with the web server and then connect to your MSS.
- You are trying to keep most people out, but some people in.  You need an authentication scheme.  This usually means a login name and password, and a secure way to transmit it.  SSL is probably what you want to look at.  You'll need a SSL certificate (you can make your own), and a client program (web browsers work) that can make SSL connections.
- You are trying to allow your users to do only some things, but not others.  You need an authorization scheme.  This is provided by the server application, such as the Windows Remote Desktop.  Without knowing how much granularity you need, it's hard to say exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

@bdares hit a bunch of your issues right on the head...

And then some... As a church, sounds of funding already ringing that they won't have that type of funding to handle... especially opening up a channel to the church management and possible accounting.  Even if offering your own SSL certificate, getting hacked is getting easier and easier.  If its a low budget operation with financial data readily easy for the taking, I'd hate to see a church (or any other legitimate non-profit organization) get messed up.

There are a lot of security issues to deal with and you can NOT take it lightly.